R bind two data frames with different time observations
I have two data frames f1 and f2
row11 <- c("a", "c", "2000", "2001", "2005")
row12 <- c("", "", 7, 10, 15)

f1 <- as.data.frame(rbind(row11, row12))

row21 <- c("a", "b", "c", "2002", "2005")
row22 <- c("", "", "", 1, 15)

f2 <- as.data.frame(rbind(row21, row22)) 

I would like to bind these two data frames in such a way, that I get the data frame f3:
row31 <- c("a", "b", "c", seq(2000,2005,1))

row32 <- c("", "", "", 7, 10, NA, NA, NA, 15)

row33 <- c("", "", "", NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 15)

f3 <- rbind(row32, row33)
colnames(f3)  <- row31 

f3:
      a  b  c  2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
row32 "" "" "" "7"  "10" NA   NA   NA   "15"
row33 "" "" "" NA   NA   "1"  NA   NA   "15"

f3 takes the column names "a", "b" and "c" and adds a time series from 2000 to 2005 with the corresponding values from f1 and f2.
I would prefer a solution with dplyr.

Don't use as.data.frame(rbind(...)) because rbind creates a matrix and therefore all values are coerced to class character. Use data.frame(...) directly.

You could try the following (mostly) dplyr solution, which defines a helper function to bind the rows after renaming and removing the first row, then orders the columns.
While I'm sure there is a more elegant way, I use a little base R to identifythe missing year columns, then back to tidyverse to add in new columns and reorder:
# helper function
f <- function(x){
  x %>%
    setNames(unlist(x[1,])) %>%
    slice(-1)
}

# combine all dfs
f3_temp <- list(f1, f2) %>%
  purrr::map(f) %>%
  bind_rows()

# Note, if all your data frames contain the pattern "f" followed by numbers,
# you could replace `list(f1, f2) %>% ... with:
f3_temp <- mget(ls(pattern = "f\\d+")) %>%
  purrr::map(f) %>%
  bind_rows()

# Identify in missing years in column names
num_names <- as.numeric(names(f3_temp))[!is.na(as.numeric(names(f3_temp)))]
new_names <- setdiff(seq(min(num_names), max(num_names), 1L), names(f3_temp))

# Add in new and reorder all columns:
f3 <- f3_temp %>% 
  tibble::add_column(!!!new_names) %>%
  mutate(across(as.character(new_names), ~ NA)) %>%
  select(order(nchar(colnames(.)), colnames(.)))

Output:
#       a    b c 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
# row12             7   10 <NA>   NA   NA   15
# row22          <NA> <NA>    1   NA   NA   15


Great, thanks! How could I adapt the first part of the code, if I don't only have two data frames but n, lets say f1, f2, ..., fn?

Hi @MPB_2022 - see edit - you can combine them into a list and use purrr::map to apply the helper function to all data frames

A simple approach to create two data frames from your row1 and row2 data frames, and then bind them using dplyr.
I transpose (t(...)) the two row vectors, row12 and row22, because the data.frame expects column inputs, not vector inputs.
Transposing the atomic vector creates a matrix that can be used for the data.frame input.
row11 <- c("a", "c", "2000", "2001", "2005")
row12 <- c("", "", 7, 10, 15)

row21 <- c("a", "b", "c", "2002", "2005")
row22 <- c("", "", "", 1, 15)

f1 <- data.frame(t(row12))
colnames(f1)<- row11

f2 <- data.frame(t(row22)) 
colnames(f2) <- row21

f3 <- dplyr::bind_rows(f1, f2)


Then, the output of f3 is below. You can rearrange the columns and can convert the numeric to character if needed.
> f3
  a c 2000 2001 2005    b 2002
1        7   10   15 <NA> <NA>
2     <NA> <NA>   15         1

And demonstration of the output of an atomic vector transpose:
> t(row12)
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,] ""   ""   "7"  "10" "15"
> t(row12) |> class()
[1] "matrix" "array" 


Another option :
### Packages
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(janitor)

### Data
row11 <- c("a", "c", "2000", "2001", "2005")
row12 <- c("", "", 7, 10, 15)
df1 <- data.frame(rbind(row11, row12))

row21 <- c("a", "b", "c", "2002", "2005")
row22 <- c("", "", "", 1, 15)
df2 <- data.frame(rbind(row21, row22))

### Promote the first rows to colnames
df1=row_to_names(df1,1)
df2=row_to_names(df2,1)

### Merge all dataframes and get the lowest and highest value for year
### You can add all your dataframes in the bind_rows step
mrg=bind_rows(df1,df2)
m1=min(as.numeric(colnames(mrg)),na.rm = TRUE)
m2=max(as.numeric(colnames(mrg)),na.rm = TRUE)

### Build a null row data frame with the missing years
newcols=setNames(rep('', length(seq.int(m1,m2))), seq.int(m1,m2))
ndf=tibble(.rows = 0) %>% add_column(!!!newcols)

### Bind it with the first one
output=bind_rows(mrg,ndf)

### Reorder the columns and type them correctly
out=output %>%
  select(sort(colnames(.)[!grepl("[0-9]",colnames(.))]),
         sort(colnames(.)[grepl("[0-9]",colnames(.))])) %>%
  mutate(across(colnames(.)[grepl("[0-9]",colnames(.))][1]:last_col(),~as.numeric(.)))

Output :
      a    b c 2000 2001 2002 2003 2004 2005
row12   <NA>      7   10   NA   NA   NA   15
row22            NA   NA    1   NA   NA   15

N.B. : row12 contains "NA" in column B (missing in the original post). It could be easily replaced if needed.
